# How can i remove a div dynamically and recreate it in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I am using ant visualization to dynamically create a chat-based on user input but the chart keeps appending to the div. I have tried including the key to div to notify the virtual dom of the change but it is still not working.

```html
<div id="containerPieChart" key={props.searchInput}>
  {props.chartData && props.chartData.length > 0 && (renderChart())}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `is still not working`? Are there console errors?  And can you show us `renderChart`?  I have a feeling instead of a div wrapping this, it should be its own component.

Comment: The renderChart makes use of the div to create the chart what I mean by its not working is that when I make use of the key attribute on the div the chart won't render but if I remove the key it keeps appending the chart to the div . The problem is instead of rendering the new chart each time the data changes it keeps appending to the div ``` const chart = new Chart({
                container: 'containerPieChart',
                autoFit: true,
                height: 500,
            });```

Comment: Hi larz thanks for reaching out, I have been able to sort it out what I did was to move the div to the parent component and set the key to div to search input and it worked.